# List of starting characters in employee names from table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

The employees list page on my rails app has a requirement of showing links for each of the starting characters in employee names, to facilitate quickly searching for users by a letter.

The link list should include only those letters which have names starting from them. Eg: If the table contains 3 names - Joe User, Jill User, and Example User - only two links `E` and `J` should be displayed.

Wondering what's the most efficient way to do this.

As a first attempt, I added a class method in the `Employee` class as follows:

```
def self.list_of_starting_characters
  array = []
  ('A'..'Z').to_a.each do |char|
    array << char unless self.where("name like '#{char}%'").count.zero?
  end 

  array
end
```

This gets called on every render of the view; so changed it to use a class variable as follows:

```
@@starting_characters_list = []

def self.list_of_starting_characters
  return @@starting_characters_list unless @@starting_characters_list.empty?

  array = []
  ('A'..'Z').to_a.each do |char|
    array << char unless self.where("name like '#{char}%'").count.zero?
  end 

  @@starting_characters_list = array
end
```

Now it is called only once per session. Are there better ways to accomplish this?

One other option I am considering is to store the list of starting characters in a separate table and update it when the employee data is modified, but worried it might be too much of a hassle, to keep the separate table in sync with the main table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
first_letters = self.pluck(:name).group_by{ |name| name[0].upcase }.keys
```

It grabs all User's names, group them by the first letter of the name and get the only the keys of the hash generated by the `group_by`.

Comment: Thanks! That does make it faster by running 1 query instead of 26 queries in my solution + it also shows that there are first names with numbers and special characters in the database.

Comment: I forgot to add a `downcase` or `upcase`: `group_by{ |name| name[0].upcase }` to make sure it is not case sensitive @PrakashMurthy

Comment: Yes, that would be useful. In my case, I don't mind it being case sensitive. Also, I used the suggested solution as a scope. Code : `scope :first_letters, -> { pluck(:first_name).group_by{ |name| name[0] }.keys }`

Comment: I did remove the `scope` from the answer because in my opinion it should not be a scope: the logic behind this is "get all first letters of the DB". A Scope is more like "get all records respecting the following conditions". (a scope returns a list of records, but the logic we need here should return a list of letters made with the records, a simple Model method shoud be enough).

Comment: That makes sense. In the interest of making it easy on the next developer, I will change my code to use it like a class method and not a scope.